# Setting up Vapor and Vapor-MySQL

Tags: vapor

My Vapor and Vapor-MySQL setup died after I tried newer versions in my Package.swift file.

Ultimately, I wanted a Package.swift that included the following:

`.Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", majorVersion: 0, minor: 16),`
`.Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/mysql-provider.git", majorVersion: 0, minor: 4)`

Then I ran 
`vapor build --mysql`   That worked.  No errors reported.

Then I flipped to Xcode to build the project and hit run.

I then hit a lot of Framework errors.  "Pathindexable". "CryptoEssentials" and "Node" frameworks.   Seemed to be linker errors.

I then ran `vapor clean`.  Cleaned my project in Xcode.  No joy.

Any idea why this did not work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The missing command was:

`vapor xcode --mysql`

This automatically prompts you to open Xcode and fixes the linker errors.

Comment: As of Vapor toolbox 10.4, you don't need to specify build flags such as `--mysql` anymore. The toolbox is smart enough to know when it needs to link such libraries